# CloudKit sign in / log in. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloudkit, touch-id

I wonder if is possible to perform a *sign in / log in* using **CloudKit**. I have researched a lot but I have not found answers.

I know to get access to CloudKit the user has to add his Apple ID, and maybe, I could use *Local Authentication* (with TouchID), but what if the iPhone doesn't have this capability?

*(CloudKit was not my first option, I prefer to use Parse but currently the version 1.7.5 is not working)*

Cheers .. !!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here. The user should already be signed in via the Settings app. In theory, you shouldn't have to worry about the actual signing in as much as if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. Otherwise, I thinking of all the process, I mean, because CloudKit is taking the values from the System (signed in via Settings), I think there is no way to log out using the app. I wonder if there is a way to really take care of everything (sign in, log in, log out, etc.).

Comment: Ah... I see. Ya, there isn't a way to do what you're suggesting. Handling login, logout, etc. Is all up to the user and the Operating System. Basically all we get is a `readonly BOOL` saying if the user is authed with iCloud.

Comment: I asked this question every day. If reminder and FaceTime has login-logout option, why not developer apps ? This is very handy if you have 2 apple accounts (normal and developer)